# Does "The investigator traveled the same week as the thief." in a logic-grid clue mean that two different people are referred to?

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

I've always wanted to know if a certain thing was expressly allowed or disallowed in logic puzzles.  Here's a specific example:

> The investigator traveled the same week as the thief.

Does this mean that the investigator and thief must be different people?  The statement could be true either way, but am unclear if I can rely on the two being different or if that's just an attempt to be tricky.  (Empirically, I usually find I can't make great progress without making the assumption they must be different people, but it feels sloppy to do so.)

(Clarification:  "investigator" and "thief" are not two members of the same set.  All characters have a profession to be logically deduced from a given set, and, one character is also secretly the thief.)

Comment: I would understand it to be talking about two different people.  Most of the time in these puzzles each person has an occupation and you would be given that they are different by the list of occupations and the fact that there is one per person

Comment: Clarification:  "investigator" and "thief" were not two members of the same set.  If that had been the case, I would have clearly understood the wording would require them to be two different people.  The overall logic puzzle had the known occupations of all parties but in addition to the occupation, one was also secretly a thief.

Comment: That would be good information to have in the question.  I think the sentence structure still indicates they are different.

Answer (score 3):

#### Probably?

Unfortunately, this is an ambiguity that really only the writer of the puzzle could clarify. If the puzzle was written by someone who isn't a logician or pedant, they *probably* intend to also say that the people mentioned should be different. Most people wouldn't even realize it's an option that they're the same person! Unfortunately, there's no globally-accepted standard for logic puzzle phrasing - the only way to know for sure what the author meant would be to ask them yourself.

You can handle this in either the way you did (assume the implication is unintended until you need to use it) or the other way around (assume the implication is intended unless that breaks the puzzle). Both have downsides - the former leaves you unsure when to make the jump of "I can't make any further deductions", while the latter could unintentionally skip the intended path if your assumption coincidentally works out. I'd personally feel pretty confident making the assumption in general, and I can't remember it ever being wrong for me personally... but it's not a 100% safe bet.

Comment: "If the puzzle was written by someone who isn't a logician or pedant, they probably intend to also say that the people mentioned should be different. Most people wouldn't even realize it's an option that they're the same person!" Good point. You can also look at the difficulty level of the question. If it's supposed to be "easy" or "normal", chances are that you're supposed to go for the average/intuitive option. Most 5x5 "Einstein's puzzles" are of average difficulty for people familiar with them, so there's that.

Comment: It's funny.  If the clue were "Alan traveled the same week as the man who lives in the blue house", I would assume they must be two different people, even though technically the same ambiguity exists.  It would feel incorrect to write a clue like that and have them refer to the same person.  I think it was precisely because "thiefness" was an extra unknown dimension that could apply to anyone that it seemed too ambiguous to rely on the thief being distinct from the investigator.